# Redirect to ReturnUrl in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this URL

> `http://localhost:49460/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fusers%2fuser%2f5199`

How do I redirect to the view `Users/User/5199`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First pass the `ReturnUrl` as a string parameter on your controller, and redirect to that string value if its not null, like so:

```
public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl){
   //logic here
   if (ReturnUrl != null){
      return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
   }
   //Default return in case ReturnUrl is null goes here
}
```